# How to determine image overlap through range of X's and Y's in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, image, overlap

So I have been attempting to create a little game of "frogger" only I used a trainer instead of a Frog and Pokemon instead of cars. Pretty simple. So far I have everything moving and resetting according to plan, but the problem arises when I try determine overlap for the trainer and the pokemon. At the moment I have coding which gets the X and Y coordinates of each and if they equal one another then the trainer resets to the beginning. Obviously I realize this means that the trainer only resets if the X and Y are both exactly the same, despite whether or not they are overlapping. So I tried to make it so that if the trainer were within a range of the get.X() and get.Y() , but that did not work. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm not all that smart when it comes to programming, I just do it as a hobby, so please keep the terminology as simple as possible :P

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new MainLoop());
        t.start();
    }

    private class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            switch (e.getKeyCode()){
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                leftKey = true;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                rightKey = true;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                upKey = true;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                downKey = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            switch (e.getKeyCode()){
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                leftKey = false;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                rightKey = false;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                upKey = false;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                downKey = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public class MainLoop implements Runnable{
        public MainLoop(){
        }
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                if(upKey){ trainer.moveUp();
                           pikachu.run();
                           squirtle.run();
                           golbat.run();
                           snivy.run();
                           snorlax.run();
                           bulbasaur.run();
                           jolteon.run();
                           espeon.run();
                           charmander.run();
                           sableye.run();
                           gardevoir.run();
                           manectric.run();}
                if(downKey){ trainer.moveDown();
                            pikachu.run();
                            squirtle.run();
                            golbat.run();
                            snivy.run();
                            snorlax.run();
                            bulbasaur.run();
                            jolteon.run();
                            espeon.run();
                            charmander.run();
                            sableye.run();
                            gardevoir.run();
                            manectric.run();}
                if(leftKey){ trainer.moveLeft();
                            pikachu.run();
                            squirtle.run();
                            golbat.run();
                            snivy.run();
                            snorlax.run();
                            bulbasaur.run();
                            jolteon.run();
                            espeon.run();
                            charmander.run();
                            sableye.run();
                            gardevoir.run();
                            manectric.run();}
                if(rightKey){ trainer.moveRight();
                            pikachu.run();
                            squirtle.run();
                            golbat.run();
                            snivy.run();
                            snorlax.run();
                            bulbasaur.run();
                            jolteon.run();
                            espeon.run();
                            charmander.run();
                            sableye.run();
                            gardevoir.run();
                            manectric.run();}
                if (trainer.getPy() == squirtle.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == squirtle.getPx()){
//                  if (squirtle.getPy() - 10 <= trainer.getPy() <= squirtle.getPy() +10 & squirtle.getPx() - 10 <= trainer.getPx() <= squirtle.getPx() +10 ){

                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == pikachu.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == pikachu.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == golbat.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == golbat.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == snivy.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == snivy.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == snorlax.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == snorlax.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == bulbasaur.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == bulbasaur.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == jolteon.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == jolteon.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == espeon.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == espeon.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == charmander.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == charmander.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == sableye.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == sableye.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == gardevoir.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == gardevoir.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() == manectric.getPy() & trainer.getPx() == manectric.getPx()){
                            trainer.dead();
                            Skully skull = new Skully (trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy());
                            }
                if (trainer.getPy() <= 25){

                }

                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex){
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawScreen(Graphics display){
        backBuffer.drawImage(background,0,0,null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Trainer, trainer.getPx(), trainer.getPy(), null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Pikachu, pikachu.getPx(), pikachu.getPy(),null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Manectric, manectric.getPx(), manectric.getPy(),null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Snivy, snivy.getPx(), snivy.getPy(), null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Snorlax, snorlax.getPx(), snorlax.getPy(), null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Bulbasaur, bulbasaur.getPx(), bulbasaur.getPy(), null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Jolteon, jolteon.getPx(), jolteon.getPy(), null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Espeon, espeon.getPx(), espeon.getPy(), null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Charmander, charmander.getPx(), charmander.getPy(), null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Sableye, sableye.getPx(), sableye.getPy(), null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Golbat, golbat.getPx(),  golbat.getPy(),null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Gardevoir, gardevoir.getPx(), gardevoir.getPy(), null);
        backBuffer.drawImage(Squirtle, squirtle.getPx(), squirtle.getPy(),null);
        display.drawImage(frontBuffer,0,0,this);
    }
    public void update(Graphics display){
        drawScreen(display);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get set up a square area for all items in the game and create a class that has the attributes top bottom left and right.

Something like this

```
public class Square {
    private int top, bottom, left, right;

    public int getTop() {
        return top;
    }

    public void setTop(int top) {
        this.top = top;
    }

    public int getBottom() {
        return bottom;
    }

    public void setBottom(int bottom) {
        this.bottom = bottom;
    }

    public int getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(int left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public int getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(int right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

After that you can use greater or lesser then to check if they are overlapping like this.

```
private boolean isOverlapping(Square first, Square second) {
    // If first is over second or under second.
    if (first.getTop() < second.getBottom() || first.getBottom() > second.getTop()) {
        // If First is to the left or to the right of second
        if (first.getLeft() > second.getRight() || first.getRight() < second.getLeft()) {
            // Return false
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Otherwise the two must be overlapping
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So I could do it that way, but there is no way to write it as I attempted to do in the commented out line? Where I wrote //                  if (squirtle.getPy() - 10 <= trainer.getPy() <= squirtle.getPy() +10 & squirtle.getPx() - 10 <= trainer.getPx() <= squirtle.getPx() +10 )

Comment: Separate every condition with && (and) or || (or), or have them as a separate if.
Something like this: 
if (squirtle.getPy() - 10 <= trainer.getPy() && squirtle.getPy() >= trainer.getPy() -10 && squirtle.getPx() - 10) <= trainer.getPx() && squirtle.getPx() >= trainer.getPx() -10)
Though i would really recommend to break it up a little to make it more readable.

Comment: Yeah I figured out that I should just make them each as nested ifs. Don't know why that blew right over my head haha. Thanks for the help though